# Why doesn't OpenGL cliping discard unvisible primitives?

Tags: c++, opengl, shader

I wrote simple OpenGL program in c++ that renders many of textured cubes (about 100000) with some lighting effects (based on Phong model).

When I move camera to position in which nothing is visible (all cubes are behind the camera), I get 19 FPS. However, when I replace fragment shader with the primitive one (which just returns fixed color) and move camera in a way all cubes (or at least most of them) are visible, I get 28 FPS, which is much more.

In my opinion, it should be otherwise, as in the first case fragment shader shouldn't be used at all (because of clipping stage between vertex and fragment shader stages), while in the second case fragment shader has to be run many times.

Is my way of thinking correct? Or maybe this function has to be enabled or something like that?

I use OpenGL 3.3 core profile on KDE Neon 5.13. 
My graphics card is Radeon HD3470 (with Mesa OpenGL implementation).

EDIT (more measurements):
Visible cubes with advanced shader: 15.5 FPS.
Visible cubes with basic shader: 28-30 FPS.
Invisible cubes with advandec shader: 18 FPS.
Invisible cubes with basic shader: 36 FPS.

Comment: Without more information it's hard to say, for example it'd be nice to know the framerate when looking at all of the lit cubes as well as not looking at the standard ones. If I had to guess it's likely something to do with clipping for some reason being very expensive when things are very far off screen like that (not being able to take advantage of some features like guard-band clipping), whereas while invoking a ton of fragment shaders is "expensive", it's also a very parallelizable task which the GPU has no problem with.

Comment: But have you checked whether pixel shader in the first case is executed or not? Are you sure that it is not non-graphics code fault? Actually you should've profiled your application to figure out what is going on.

Comment: It is rather odd that the introduction of a different fragment shader would cause such radical performance difference even when nothing is being drawn, I'd suspect it's something more along the lines as what @VTT said at this point, likely some code you have on the CPU side causing the issues, such as perhaps uploading lighting information depending on how you're doing that. Without full knowledge of how your pipeline is structured or what's going on it's still difficult to say.

Comment: Have you tried this on another PC / driver / hardware? It might just as well be that the Mesa implementation does not care too much and just invokes the shaders without it actually being necessary.

Comment: Clipping geometry which is not visible at all (culling or visible surface determination) is the responsibility of your program not of the OpenGL implementation. No OpenGL program with complex scenes ever uses the depth buffer alone for this task. Use some kind of scene graph for space partitioning and send only the cubes which are partially or fully visible.